# Migrate part of Google Cloud BigQuery table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We have a BigQuery table, where we continuously store data. So the table is always growing.

Later on that data is used for reports, billing (sometimes debugging) etc.
Since the table is continuously growing, we noticed that our queries are taking longer time and cost more than usual.

We suppose that it is related to the fact that we did not enable partition for that table (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#create_a_time-unit_column-partitioned_table).
Our queries usually done against relatively fresh entries (no more than 90 days back), so hopefully partitioning will help.

We are thinking of creating a table with the same schema, but enabled partitioning.

After we create the table we want to populate it with the last 100 days from the old table in order to make some queries.
I've checked documentation and found that it is possible to either clone a table or take a table's snapshot. But it looks like it will not work for our case.

So my question is: is there any good (and cost-efficient) way to move data from one table to another? Both tables are going to be within same dataset.

For now I am thinking of migrating data using SQL: `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our case was solved by following:

1. First I had to migrate our database from US region to EU region (because initially database was created in the wrong region)
   I did that using following command:

```
bq mk \
  --transfer_config \
  --project_id=<project_id> \
  --data_source=cross_region_copy \
  --target_dataset=<database_eu_name> \
  --display_name="copy ds from us to eu" \
  --params='{"source_dataset_id":"<database_us_name>","source_project_id":"<project_id>", "overwrite_destination_table": "true"}'
```

After this command the data transfer job is created, which is scheduled to execute data transfer every day. Don't forget to remove it after the job is done. Perhaps there are parameters, which you can specify to do this job only once.
2. I created a new empty table with the same schema, but partitioning enabled.
3. I transferred data from the old table (in EU region) to the new empty table with partitioning enabled using following clause:

```
INSERT INTO `<project>.<database_eu>.<empty_partitioned_table>`(timestamp, column2, ...)
SELECT timestamp, column2, ...
FROM `<project>.<database_eu>.<old_table>`
WHERE
   timestamp >= TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 100 DAY))
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope it can help.

You can use the following query :

```sql
CREATE TABLE `project.dataset.table_copy`
PARTITION BY
  DATE_TRUNC(yourTimestamp, DAY)
AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM
    `project.dataset.table`
);
```

With `PARTITION BY` you specify the needed partition in the new table, in this case I shown an example with a partition per day but you can change it.

No need to specify the schema because it is deducted from the current `table` in the select bloc.

Comment: Thank you for the query! I will try to use it soon unless anyone suggests more optimal solution